# jquery .append iframe animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, append

I am trying to write a page that allows multiple buttons to be clicked on within my webpage and for iframes to load the content sliding down and knocking other content further down as they load.

I have tried various different ways to make this scroll up and down by using the jquery .animate functions but for some reason I just cannot get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe").click(function() {
            var file = $(this).attr("data-url");
            var size = $(this).attr("data-size");
            $(this).parent('article').append("<iframe class='articleframe' height='" + size + "' src='" + file + "'>Moo</iframe>"); 
            $(this).siblings('.open').css('display','inline-block');
            $(this).hide();
        });
    $(".open").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).siblings('.iframe').css('display','inline-block');
            $(this).siblings('.articleframe').remove();
    });
});

<article>
    <h2>Querybox</h2>
    <h5 class="button iframe" data-url="http://www.bbc.co.uk" data-size="900px"  >Load another file</h5>
    <h5 class='button open'>Hide Frame</h5>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of a visual dependence [:) fiddlywiddly](http://jsfiddle.net/TV7mU/3/)

You may have to tweak this to your specifications but this will do the trick:

### Javascript:

*Change '.append()' to '.prepend()'*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".iframe").click(function () {
        var file = $(this).data("url");
        var size = $(this).data("size");
        var $one = $('#one');
        $one.prepend("<h5 class='button open'>Hide Frame</h5><div class='frame-contain'><iframe class='articleframe' height=0 src='" + file + "'></iframe></div>");
        var $wrap = $one.find('.frame-contain:first');
        $wrap.animate({
            height: size
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).height(now);
                $(this).nextAll('.frame-contain').offsetParent().top += now;
                $(this).find('iframe').height(now);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $(".open").click(function () {
                    $(this).next('div').slideUp(1000);
                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I would also suggest re-arranging your elements but that's up to you.  You can put your `<h5>` buttons into a `<header>` and the `<iframe>` creations into a `<section>`.  Food for thought.  That way your buttons don't go flying all over the place.  My example utilizes this idea.

### HTML:

```
<article>
    <header>
         <h2>Querybox</h2>
         <h5 class="button iframe" data-url="http://www.bbc.co.uk" data-size="900">Load another file</h5> 
    </header>
    <section id="one"></section>
</article>
```

### CSS:

```
iframe, header, section, div {
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
section, div {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.open {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}
.articleframe {
    float: left;
}
```

Since I am uncertain of your end-game here I made my best interpretation.  Keep in mind this code is horribly inefficient the way it is set-up (so many selectors utilizing jQuery is very code intensive).

I would suggest you put more `id` tags on things and reference those using `$(document.getElementById('id'))` or `$(document.querySelector('#id'))`.  Also, using jQuery `.width()` and `.height()` takes a huge hit as well.  You should use a javascript native selector and then apply `.innerWidth = XX` or `.innerHeight = XX`.

Normally performance at this small of scale isn't hugely important but given what you're displaying and the impact it has on the browser, it may help you.

For examples on the performance gain:  [JSPerf - innerHeight vs. .height()](http://jsperf.com/innerheight-vs-height)